# How to save a file after parsing it with ANTLR (using java)?

Tags: java, antlr4, translate, filewriter, code-translation

I'm working on a project where I am taking a C source file and inject some code at the beginning of every function call. `Main` loads the file and turns it into a string.

**Main.java**

```
            String inputFilename = args[0];
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFilename));
            String code = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            Translator translator = new Translator(code);
            translator.translate();
```

The translator class creates the `ANTLRInputStream`, `CLexer`, `CParser` and `CommonTokenStream`. Then it walks the tree using the `CodeListener` class.

**Translator.java**

```
public Translator(String code){
    ANTLRInputStream inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(code);
    CLexer lexer = new CLexer(inputStream);
    tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    CParser parser = new CParser(tokens);
    parseTree = parser.compilationUnit();
}

void translate(){
    walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    CodeListener listener = new CodeListener(tokens);
    walker.walk(listener, parseTree);
    parsedCode = listener.rewriter.getText();
    saveFile();
}

void saveFile(){
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"))){
        out.print(parsedCode);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The `CodeListener` Class inserts a comment, `//hey look a function` at the beginning of the function body.

**CodeListener.java**

```
public TokenStreamRewriter rewriter;
String parsedCode = "";
 @Override
public void enterFunctionDefinition(CParser.FunctionDefinitionContext ctx) {

    String returnType = ctx.declarationSpecifiers().getText();
    String functionBody = ctx.compoundStatement().getText();
    rewriter.insertBefore(ctx.compoundStatement().getStart(), "//hey look a function ");
}
```

I found the modified stream, but is there a way I can get the newly modified code? How do I save it into a file such as `parsedcode.c`, as shown in the example below?

**code.c**

```
int main(){ 
    foo();
    bar();
}

void foo(){
   //does something
}

void bar(){
   //does something else
}
```

**parsedcode.c**

```
int main(){
    //hey look a function 
    foo();
    bar();
}

void foo(){
   //hey look a function
   //does something
}

void bar(){
   //hey look a function
   //does something else
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just call `toString()` or whatever on the `TokenStreamRewriter` and save the string?

Comment: Yes, just got that to work, I need to include white space though. I changed the grammar to send on a channel `WS : [ \t\n\r] -> channel(WHITESPACE);` before it was`WS : [ \t\n\r] -> skip;` and then included `@lexer::members{
    public static final int WHITESPACE = 1;
}` Found that in the book thanks for the help!